# How to use an Array mapping in ES?

Tags: elasticsearch

I wanted to create a mapping for `movies` that look like:

```
{
   title: "The Artist",
   genres: ["Drama", "Comedy"]
}
```

In the [ElasticSearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-array-type.html) I see this example:

```
"properties" : {
        "message" : {"type" : "string"},
        "tags" : {"type" : "string", "index_name" : "tag"},
        ...
  }
```

However, now I am confused.. What I expected to see was:

```
 "properties" : {
     "message" : {"type" : "string"},
      "tags" : {"type" : "array"}
  }
```

So, why does the example just provide a reference to another index? How would I define that "tags" index? Or, when would I use that Array mapping?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

So ElasticSearch doesn't need to specify that a mapping is an array. You can treat any mapping as an array by using square brackets:

```
{
    title: ["The Artist", "Formerly known as Prince" ],
    genres: ["Drama", "Comedy"],
    ...
}
```

See the last sentence on the page:

> We could, of course, name the field as tag and skip the index_name all together

The "index_name" mapping just allows you to define an alias in the plural form of tag -> tags.

Comment: +1 for the price reference, and the nice responce =P